# why previously inserted data is inserting on each page refresh?PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code here. It successfully inserts data into database but every time I refresh my browser I receive this message from the browser.To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.When I press resend, it Inserts the same data that I inserted.can anyone tell me whats the problem is and solve it.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("task");
    if(isset($_POST['show'])) {
        mysql_query("insert into `test` (`name`) value ('".$_POST['name']."')");
        $sel=mysql_query("select * from `test` order by id DESC"); ?>

        <table>
            <?php   
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) { ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>                  
                </tr>

            <?php } ?>
        </table>

    <?php } ?>

<html>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" name="show" value="show" />
    </form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['show'])) {
        mysql_query("insert into `test` (`name`) value ('".$_POST['name']."')");
        header('location:INDEX.PHP');   
    }
?>

<table>
    <?php   
        $sel=mysql_query("select * from `test` order by id DESC");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I added this: header('location:INDEX.PHP'); before if block's closing.Now what happens is data is being inserted and the page is showing new index.php page with no fields.What i want is all the fields from the table test.

Comment: Go for this:

<?php
if(isset($_POST['show']))
{
   mysql_query("insert into `test` (`name`) value ('".$_POST['name']."')");
  header('location:INDEX.PHP');   
  }
  ?>
  
  <table>
   <?php   
 $sel=mysql_query("select * from `test` order by id DESC");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
        {
   ?>
     <tr><td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td></tr>
    <?php
       }
      ?>
    </table>

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the unset() function in the code to unset the `$_POST`:

```
if(isset($_POST['show'])) {
    unset($_POST['show']); //use unset here
    mysql_query("insert into `test` (`name`) value ('".$_POST['name']."')");
    $sel=mysql_query("select * from `test` order by id DESC");?>
    <table>
        <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sel)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I tried as you told but its not working.Same thing is happening even after using unset function.Broken Heart ღ

Comment: @user3045432 try `unset($_POST);` instead of `unset($_POST['show']);`

Comment: Broken Heart ღ I tried that as well but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page you have submitted data to, it resends the request.

And please sanitize your variables, you're vulnerable to SQL injection.

And please stop using mysql. It's deprecated, use mysqli instead of PDO.

Comment: can you please explain what sanitizing variable means in current scenario?
@RUJordan

Comment: I means escaping characters such as backslashes, quotes, etc. Somebody could input something into the POST request that will be ran as a query, and it could drop your table, get personal data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

redirect your page with header function

```
header("location:page.php");
```

or unset the value with unset function

```
unset($variable);
```

there are many ways, but first you've to search.